# How do you restrict a blender 2.8 add-on to a specific main tab?

Tags: python, blender

Blender 2,8
Windows 10x64

I would like to restrict an add-on via python to be attached to the Sculpting tab when it is selected.  I have looked through the docs and cannot find a setting to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

use bl_context = "sculpt_mode"

> bl_context = "mesh_edit", "curve_edit", "surface_edit", "text_edit",
>   "armature_edit", "mball_edit", "lattice_edit", "posemode",
>   "sculpt_mode", "weightpaint", "vertexpaint", "imagepaint",
>   "particlemode", "objectmode"
>
> bl_space_type = "EMPTY", "VIEW_3D", "TIMELINE", "GRAPH_EDITOR",
>   "DOPESHEET_EDITOR", "NLA_EDITOR", "IMAGE_EDITOR", "SEQUENCE_EDITOR",
>   "CLIP_EDITOR", "TEXT_EDITOR", "NODE_EDITOR", "LOGIC_EDITOR",
>   "PROPERTIES", "OUTLINER", "USER_PREFERENCES", "INFO", "FILE_BROWSER",
>   "CONSOLE"
>
> bl_region_type = "WINDOW", "HEADER", "CHANNELS", "TEMPORARY", "UI",
>   "TOOLS", "TOOL_PROPS", "PREVIEW"